# Is it possible to have some kind of dynamic KeyFilter in autofac?

Tags: c#, dynamic, dependency-injection, autofac, constructor-injection

KeyFilter used in Autofac is helpful but really I think it's not dynamic because the key here is preset/setup/defined and attached to constructor parameters at compile time. No way to have something similar working at runtime.

Here is the scenario, at the time resolving for some instance, the key can be determined (which can change dynamically based on the current context). That key then should be taken into account before resolving for the instance. I think `Multitenant` feature supported by autofac is something very close to that requirement. However I don't think it can be easily used and supports constructor injection (we may have to always create a scope and resolve for instances explicitly and manually, which looks much like a service locator's way).

So applied that imaginary feature in code version picking example, let's see how helpful it can be. Suppose I have 2 implementations for a same interface, each corresponds to one code version (v1 and v2). Now the constructor consuming that interface does not care about which version, but the context will provide the IoC container which version so that it should resolve for the correct implementation corresponding to the that version.

```
public interface ISender {
    void Send(string msg);
}
//version v1 
public class SlowSender : ISender {
    //...
}
//version v2
public class FastSender : ISender {
    //...
}
```

Now's the consumer class:

```
public class MyConsumer {
    readonly ISender _sender;
    public MyConsumer(ISender sender){
        _sender = sender;
    }
    //do whatever with what ISender provides
}
```

So here when resolving for `MyConsumer`, autofac should know about which version it is to pick for me, such as via some context info provider like this:

```
public class ContextInfoProvider : IContextInfoProvider //just an example
{
    public string GetCurrentVersion(){
        //can return some value picked from HttpContext.Current.Request
        //or any ambient variable that can be injected at some very early time.
    }
}
```

That's kind of a service (very fast service) to help autofac know of which should be taken into account (as an input, a parameter) for the instance resolving process.

I know this is possible but may have not been implemented yet by autofac. It's really a pity. Do you have any alternative solution with the current features supported by autofac? Please note that I don't want to use service-locator-like code, sometimes we have to use it that way but almost the time we need a constructor-dependency-injection's way, it's just neat and clean.

Comment: There are no miracles in programming. Autofac cannot know it by itself. You have to provide some piece of code that will be generating/calculating/fetching/<...> key for resolving your service from the autofac container.
Right now you can write something like ISenderFactory which will resolve service from autofac's container based on the key provided from your algorithm.

Comment: If you read my question thoroughly, you should have noticed that I mentioned about a way to help ioc container know about that key, (the `IContextInfoProvider`). Of course this is not very miracle, it's possible but pity that not yet (or never) be implemented. I have some workarounds in mind but really not clean as what I described in my question. Using a factory is also a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register a lambda. Put the factory logic in that lambda.

```cs
builder.Register(ctx =>
  var version = ctx.Resolve<IContextInfoProvider>().GetVersion();
  if(version == 1)
  {
    return new SlowSender();
  }
  return new FastSender();
).As<ISender>();
```

Comment: thank you, I am trying this approach, still implementing code, I'll be back with some result. In the mean time I may have another question asked in SO.

Comment: BTW do you have any idea to save an environment variable (from http request) in some static variable (defined in my class) ***as soon as possible*** so that it happens before the Autofac resolving process? I've tried preparing the environment variables in `OnActionExecuting` but looks like it's too late. Somehow the controller's dependencies are resolved first (so autofac runs first) before `OnActionExecuting` runs (so the environment variables are unavailable at the time resolving my dependencies).

Comment: HttpRequest doesn't have anything to do with environment variables, and if you do get something from the request you should never store it as static because the request _changes every request_. I'd recommend doing some research on this since using request variables (including during resolution time) is very common and there are examples of it all over. If it still isn't clear, that's a new SO question rather than an add-on to this one.

Comment: I meant the environment variable ***comes from http request***, and those kind of variables ***exist per request lifetime***. So maybe you understand it differently. Actually I've just thought of ***http module*** which is replaced by ***middleware*** in asp.net core. That should work, thank you anyway. I'll come back this question with some result.

Comment: I've successfully implemented the version switching feature based on middleware in ASP.NET Core (with the help of the new feature named `Endpoint Routing` because we need the Route Data before MVC middleware), of course with the help of your answer as well (about using a factory to resolve instances). Thanks